# Predict binary outcome with R

Tags: r, categorical-data

I posted my original question here, but was told that I should have posted at Cross Validated, below is the link to the original question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943584/predict-binary-outcome-with-r?noredirect=1#comment31453858_20943584

thanks!

Comment: I've flagged your original question to recommend its migration. Your question doesn't seem to be a programming problem, but a statistical problem, so it does belong here. So does [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20943695/2829605) you've already received, which I voted up; I would've given the same answer myself.

Comment: Thanks Nick, sorry I didnt know this rule, but will keep it in mind next time posting statistics related questions.

Comment: No problem! Common mistake. :) Some of these Stack Exchange sites have picky moderators; others just let it be as long as it gets answered. The main cost is to you as the asker; you're more likely to receive answers from statisticians than programmers over here. (Or so I would assume...)

Answer (score 1):

@Perri Ma .Factor analysis won't work because it is predominantly a dimension reduction technique rather than predictive modelling. There are multiple ways to go about it

1) Statistics : Use logistic regression the glm package in R serves that. It is the most common method used for the type of problems that you asked.

2) Machine Learning methods : Basically what you want to do is predictive classification, i.e predicting accepted or terminated. The most common methods here are SVM( Support Vector Machine), Neural Networks,Decision Trees.

I suggests you start with building logistic regression model first then read into the machine learning methods. Even though the concepts of ML methods are bit difficult at first but there lots of packages to implement and result interpretation is quite easy

Comment: I used the glm function: `glm(formula = status ~ age + sex + race + grade + tenure, family = binomial, data = data)`, it returned Coefficients of the variables. While I need to interpret those coefficients, how can I use glm to include all variables in the table rather than using "~ variable 1 + variable 2 +..."?

Comment: @PerriMa I'm not completely sure but you can try this 

glm(status~.,data=data,family=binomial) 

Let me know if this works. I dont what other arguments did you pass but just change the formula part and keep rest as it is

Comment: I tried both statements: `glm(data$status~, family = binomial)` and `glm(status~, data = data, family = binomial)`, both gave me this error message: `Error: unexpected ',' in "glm(status~,"` :(

Comment: @Perri Ma , You have to put a "dot"after the sign. It should be like this 
status~.  or  this data$status~.
I hope this helps

Comment: I added "." `glm(data$status ~ . family = binomial)` and get this error message: `glm(data$status ~ . family = binomial)`. I also tried use ".," `glm(data$status ~ ., family = binomial)` and get this error message: `Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) :   '.' in formula and no 'data' argument`. Any clue :(

Comment: @PerriMa, you forgot to supply the data
your code line should be     

    glm(status~. , data=data,family=binomial)
I myself tried it . it is working

Comment: I tried again with the same statement as yours: `glm(status ~ ., data = data, family = binomial)`, now it is giving me this error message: `Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels`. Something wrong with my variables? All categorical variables have to have more than 2 levels?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12326/discussion-between-ng-21-and-perri-ma)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, one way to solve this is through multivariable logistic regression. You can fit a model that predicts the probability of outcome (Status) from the other variables:

> fit <- lrm(Status ~ Age + Tenure + Function + ...)

There are several packages that can help:  `glm` was already mentioned, and I like `rms`. Check out the documentation in `rms` because it has a detailed example for exactly your kind of problem, that you can work through. There are several books on logistic regression, including [one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441929185) by `rms`'s author.